# Passing controller logic, like "@answers = Answer.all", to Active Admin partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, partials

I created this partial in the dashboards.rb file for Active Admin. I need to pass variables to the partial so it can render that data out on the dashboard section of /Admin. I need to create the equations in a controller, or somewhere where the partial can get at it, and pass them to the partial. Where can I do that in active admin?

```
# == Render Partial Section
  # The block is rendered within the context of the view, so you can
  # easily render a partial rather than build content in ruby.
  #
    section "Month One Statistics" do
      div do
        render 'recent_graphs' # => this will render /app/views/admin/dashboard/_recent_posts.html.erb
       end
     end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the wiki, it has a good explanation, as well as other *goodies* here:

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Updated link and answer.